# Unable to resolve promise when using async await with babel and ES6 promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, babeljs, es6-promise

I have the following node app containing an async function, awaiting an ES6 promise.

```
async function test(id){
    try {
        let val = await Promise.resolve(id);
        console.log("val: " + val);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("error: " + error);
    }
}

test(1);
```

Result = val: undefined

Expected result: val: 1

I use gulp-babel to compile this to ES5.

I have the following set within the gulp task:

```
.pipe(babel({ optional: ["es7.asyncFunctions"] }))
```

I am also requiring in 'babel/polyfill' after npm installing babel.

Transpiled code:

```
function test(id) {
var val;
return regeneratorRuntime.async(function test$(context$1$0) {
    while (1) switch (context$1$0.prev = context$1$0.next) {
        case 0:
            context$1$0.prev = 0;
            context$1$0.next = 3;
            return Promise.resolve(id);

        case 3:
            val = context$1$0.sent;

            console.log('val: ' + val);
            context$1$0.next = 10;
            break;

        case 7:
            context$1$0.prev = 7;
            context$1$0.t0 = context$1$0['catch'](0);

            console.log('error: ' + context$1$0.t0);

        case 10:
        case 'end':
            return context$1$0.stop();
    }
}, null, this, [[0, 7]]);
}

test(1);
```

Comment: Can you show the transpiled code maybe?

Comment: Hm, that looks like it should work. Odd.

Comment: In my experience it is not a good practice to use try catch statements with promises. That's why you have API calls like Promise.fail(). But I am not familiar with how Babel handles promises, so I could be wrong.

Comment: @tutiplain One of the advantages of async/await is that you're supposed to be able to use try/catch with it.

Comment: I think you're supposed to await a promise itself, not the result of a `Promise.resolve()` call. For example, it should work if you got a reference to a promise from some library that uses promises, e.g. `var promise = myLibrary.asyncMethod()`, and then do `let val = await promise`.

Comment: @Matt Browne `Promise.resolve` *does* return a Promise.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Babel? When I run it with `babel-node` I get `val: 1`.

Comment: I have just come back to this making sure I have all the latest dependencies installed and it now works.  A full example can be found here: https://github.com/dbillingham/es7asyncawait

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be using a version of Babel prior to Babel version `5.5.0`. Before this version, it was possible to have `regenerator` (a dependency of Babel) installed at a version less than `0.8.28`, which is the first version where `regenerator` started supporting `await Promise.resolve(value)` (the code in your example).

Support was added in [this](https://github.com/facebook/regenerator/commit/a4d2143bc8a8c639e90471942c63df89c7a22064) commit on the `regenerator` side, and Babel upgraded to require at least the `0.8.28` release of regenerator with [this](https://github.com/babel/babel/commit/5d617ea99ba3c0ffcda5bd7f2406f647e211b295) commit.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to await test function.
Because of test function await a Promise, so wait test function when you call it in other context will help you wait until it completed.